# perl secure interpolation of substitution string containing match variables

Tags: regex, perl

The regex contains a capture group, but the substitution pattern is not interpolated to reference the match variable `$1` in

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = '([^ ]+)e s';
my $subst = '$1 ';

my $text = 'fine sand';

print $text =~ s/$regex/$subst/r;
print "\n";
```

The result is

> $1 and

The solution to [Perl regular expression variables and matched pattern substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089551/perl-regular-expression-variables-and-matched-pattern-substitution) suggests to use the `e` modifier and `eval` in the substitution; and indeed

```
print $text =~ s/$regex/eval $subst/er;
```

would give the desired

> finand

However, in my situation, the pattern and substitution strings are read from third party user input, so they cannot be considered safe for `eval`. Is there a way to interpolate the substitution string in a more secure way than to execute it as code? All I seek here is to expand all match variables contained in the substitution string.

The best I can currently think of involves an idiom like

```
$text =~ /$regex/;
sprintf $subst, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, ...
```

This would require a slight change in syntax for the substitution string, but I consider this acceptable. However, the set of imaginable match variables is infinite, in particular named match variables would not be supported.

Answer (score 3):

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( sub_copy );

print sub_copy( $text, $regex, $subst );
```

Handles replacements `'\$1.00'` and `'${1}00'` like Perl would.

Note that while this is safe from accidental/malicious information leakage and accidental/malicious code execution, it's not safe in every sense of the word. Specifically, it's quite easy to craft a regex and string combination that will take longer than the lifespan of the universe to match.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

- use [capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups) to pick up all the groups
- replace `$\d+` in `$subst` with the entries of the capture groups
- now do the substitution using the interpolated `$subst`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = '([^ ]+)e s';
my $subst = '$1 ';

my $text = 'fine sand';

print $text =~ s{$regex}{
    my @captured = @{^CAPTURE};
    $subst =~ s/\$([1-9]\d*)/$captured[$1-1]/rg
}er . "\n";
```

The re expression is safe since we only match digits and use that to index into `@captured`.  You'll need to add bounds checking. @ikegami
correctly notes it doesn't handle escaped `$` either, which isn't hard to address.

Note also that using an untrusted `$regex` creates risk of DDOS-style attacks.

Comment: Good point on missing the escaping mechanism.  However, when I test your first case I get `$x-$2`.  Yes, `String::Substitution` is a better solution.

Comment: shoot. my bad. _

Comment: [Earlier comment with misinformation removed]: It probably should provide an mechanism, so we can do `my $subst = '\$1.00';` and `my $subst = '${1}00';`. And the repeated matches against the same string are needlessly wasteful.

Comment: Fixed the performance issue.